# Can div element use formControlName?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms, forms

I am using angular 2. I am working on a form where I need to display a list of addresses and select one of them. I was initially using radio button for the same but the requirement has changed and we are displaying it as a div block. I want to know if we can use

```
<div formControlName="controlName">
```

within a div element like above? If not then how do we use form Control with div?

Also additionally when w click on one address block, it should change the background color to change the display as selected and a tick mark should appear on the top right corner of the block. I am able to display this style change when not using the loop but I m unable to use the style change in a loop of addresses

This form has multiple such blocks and in every block the address selection is mandatory and in every block we will have multiple addresses. So there is a main loop within which I have the address loop.

This works well with the radio button but I am not sure if same is the case with div. Please guide me.

Comment: You mean wrapping some `input` into div?

Comment: No without input element only div

Comment: Then you should implement custom `ControlValueAccessor` like `RadioControlValueAccessor` and `SelectControlValueAccessor`

Comment: Can I do it this way Display the options to be selected in div and have a hidden radio button and then on clicking the div the radio button gets selected and the div background color changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirement we needed to change the display of the items. So instead of creating a new component to add formcontrol to the div, added a hidden radio button and pushed the value using abstract control....Thank u all for the inputs....

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), and create a component/directive as new **custom form control**.

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'div-select-buttons',
  providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => DivSelectButtonsComponent),
        multi: true
    }
  ],
  template: `<div>your inputs</div>`,
})
class DivSelectButtonsComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    // implementation ControlValueAccessor interface
}
```

and then use it as form control like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div-select-buttons formControlName="controlName"></div-select-buttons>
</form>
```